# scikit-learn install and use

Tags: python, windows, installation, scikit-learn

I have installed WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.1

I am trying to play around with scikit - learn but when I use the code:

```
    From sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

I get SyntaxError: Invalid syntax inside of the Spyder coding app. 
Do I still need to run all this pip stuff I read about even though I am using WinPython?

Comment: Then this is probably a bug in your installation of Spyder not related with scikit-learn. But unless you provide the full traceback in your question details there is no way to tell.

Answer (score 2):

```
From sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

should be:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

"from" should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

`from` is a [keyword](http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/ref/keywords.html) with a lowercase `F`. The reason a `SyntaxError` is raised is because you have typed it with an uppercase `f`, when it should be lowercase.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

The reason it isn't a `NameError` (as it would probably expect a variable called `From`) is because of the `import`, which python identifies.